# How would I represent combinations of fixed subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given a friendship group of $n$ people, the binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}$ can tell me how many combinations of $k$ friends there are who could meet, e.g., if there are $10$ people and we meet in groups of $6$, that's 
$${ 10 \choose 6} = \frac{10!}{6!(10-6)!} = \frac{10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7}{24} = 10 \times 3 \times 7= 210 $$ combinations.

However, what if $n$ people are actually $n/2$ couples and couples always remain together, e.g. at a dinner party. The actual answer now is simply a combination of $k/2$ couples from $n/2$ couples.

But if you want to explicitly retain the information 
$k/2$ distinct pairs, what might that look like in formal notation? It's a combination of subsets from a group of subsets but what would it look like?

Comment: Apologies for not using proper maths formatting, I can't see how to get expressions in-line properly.

Comment: ps: not homework. I was thinking about covid lockdown maths :)

Comment: You can essentially treat every couple as a "person" ... That's how you solve it.

Comment: @MattiP. I already said that in my question. I'm asking about representing the problem, without losing the information it's couples, not the numeric answer which is of course n/2 C k/2

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site. You can get inline math and displayed equations by enclosing them in single and double dollar signs, respectively.